# What are the main sources of the social constructivist view in the philosophy of science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, sociology, constructivism

What are the main sources of the social constructivist view in the philosophy of science?

I am looking for the main books that introduce or develop this view of science.

Comment: See [The Social Dimensions of Scientific Knowledge](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-knowledge-social/) and [Social Ontology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/social-ontology/).

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article on [constructivist epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivist_epistemology) may provide the key references and overview you are looking for.  Regarding [philosophy of science and constructivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivist_epistemology#Constructivism_in_philosophy_of_science) they write:

> [Thomas Kuhn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Kuhn) argued that changes in scientists' views of reality not only contain subjective elements, but result from group dynamics, "revolutions" in scientific practice and changes in ["paradigms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm_shift). As an example, Kuhn suggested that the Sun-centric [Copernican "revolution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copernican_Revolution) replaced the Earth-centric views of Ptolemy not because of empirical failures, but because of a new "paradigm" that exerted control over what scientists felt to be the more fruitful way to pursue their goals.

They provide [this link](http://turkpsikiyatri.org/arsiv/kuhn-ssr-2nded.pdf) to Kuhn's *The Structure of Scientific Revolutions*.

Some of the [historical influences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivist_epistemology#History) they mention include [Gaston Bachelard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Bachelard), [Ludwek Fleck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwik_Fleck), [J. L. Austin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._L._Austin), and [Niklas Luhmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niklas_Luhmann) as well as many others.

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, September 18). Constructivist epistemology. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 23:36, September 21, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Constructivist_epistemology&oldid=916358664